# Ubuntu start up Rails on boot up

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, unix, ubuntu

I want to start my Rails server with the following command on boot up:

```
cd /home/ubuntu/app && bundle exec rails server -p 8080 -e production
```

I placed it inside the /etc/rc.local, but it never starts up the server. If I remove `bundle exec` then shell complains about not finding the `rails` command.

Both variants, with and without `bundle exec`, work if I log in, and execute it manually.

I am totally lost. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would run production mode in apache and passenger

Answer (score 0):

Try to change a user

```
su ubuntu && cd /home/ubuntu/app && bundle exec rails server -p 8080 -e production
```

Answer (score 0):

Running your script as root is not a good idea, so you want to change user before starting your code.

su is indeed the command you want to use, but you need to realise that all arguments are passed to the login shell. So the following won't work (assuming `fofox` is your username):

```
su fofox pwd
```

as you're effectively saying

```
/bin/bash /bin/pwd
```

but `/bin/pwd` does not contain a list of shell commands, so both will give an error message:

```
/bin/pwd: /bin/pwd: cannot execute binary file
```

Thus you need to add something to the shell saying you're passing a list of commands, like this:

```
/bin/bash -c /bin/pwd
```

The last wrinkle is that you want to pass a number of arguments to the su command but protect them from the shell, as

```
su fofox -c id && id
```

will show you that the first bit is executed as fofox and the second part as root again. Single quotes are used to prevent the root shell to see the `&&` characters.

So the final command becomes:

```
su fofox -c 'cd /home/ubuntu/app && bundle exec rails server -p 8080 -e production'
```